# Merge two certificate bundles into one file with no duplicates

Tags: bash, file, merge, base64, certificate

I have two bundles (several hundreds certificates each) encoded in base64 so:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
hash
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
hash2
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
hash3
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
(...)
```

Several certificates (quite a lot I would say) are present in both bundles, some are unique.

I need to merge them in one file and avoid any duplicates. I was trying sort - but since each certificate is several lines, this just scrambled the hell out of the files.

I'm not married to a one-liner idea - just anything that gets the job done, without having to mindboglingly search through each file manually.

EDIT:
I have an idea, and started some actions towards it. So basically I managed to split the bundles into separate files:

I've made a small step... Using awk I separated the files into single certificates:

```
$ cat bundle-t.crt | awk '/BEGIN/ { i++; } /BEGIN/, /END/ { print > i ".t.extracted.crt" }'
$ cat bundle-a.crt | awk '/BEGIN/ { i++; } /BEGIN/, /END/ { print > i ".a.extracted.crt" }'
```

Now I have over 400 files named 1.t.exctracted.crt, 1.a.extracted.crt and so on. All of them have different names, some have same content. 
The next step would be to find the ones with duplicate content which seems evenly difficult.

Comment: You could loop on certificates, obtain the fingerprint of each.  If you have seen it before (keep a list), keep going.   If you have never seen it before, add it to the target bundle.  That being said, there is no [mcve], your question will most likely be closed.

Comment: I suggest you read each certificate to build a single variable by concatenating the lines together without spaces or newlines. Then you will have something you can compare against each other? Perhaps build a big space separated string of all the hashes you find so you can search it quickly. You probably also want to simultaneously read the current hash in to another variable as multiple tokens 1-per-line, so that if you decide to keep it you can write it out as it originally looked.

Comment: Define bundles. One file with multiple certificates?

Comment: yes - several hundreds of base64 encoded certificates in one file. It's used to authenticate and allow incoming traffic.

Comment: I've moved a bit forward - edited the description

Answer (score 1):

Well, 
Quite easy once you realize that md5sum only hashes the content and ignores filename.
So the final solution is a 3-liner:

```
$ cat bundle-t.crt | awk '/BEGIN/ { i++; } /BEGIN/, /END/ { print > i ".t.extracted.crt" }'
$ cat bundle-a.crt | awk '/BEGIN/ { i++; } /BEGIN/, /END/ { print > i ".a.extracted.crt" }'
$ ls *.*.extracted.crt | while read file; do md5sum $file; done > ../sumy.txt
```

and this provides a neat list of hash and corresponding filename, that I can paste into excel and sort to find dupllicates:

```
81c3813ccb2e70195fff2d32981ee379  122.t.extracted.crt
81c3813ccb2e70195fff2d32981ee379  123.a.extracted.crt
4e1c95dabb928f48a1376405cdf47fa5  123.t.extracted.crt
4e1c95dabb928f48a1376405cdf47fa5  124.a.extracted.crt
5a378ac46ea08bfa63fd150f48deecf8  124.t.extracted.crt
5a378ac46ea08bfa63fd150f48deecf8  125.a.extracted.crt
fb4dc4aec9bc307fa7d4b8dbb9abe7d7  125.t.extracted.crt
fb4dc4aec9bc307fa7d4b8dbb9abe7d7  126.a.extracted.crt
d62005dd9d237147998f9dbfb37ce8f1  126.t.extracted.crt
d62005dd9d237147998f9dbfb37ce8f1  127.a.extracted.crt
97c19f5ba9e0859dd5d40beebfe67d39  127.t.extracted.crt
97c19f5ba9e0859dd5d40beebfe67d39  128.a.extracted.crt
9d5376bfef27a0b1518abc401b4e6085  128.t.extracted.crt
9d5376bfef27a0b1518abc401b4e6085  129.a.extracted.crt
4ac1beb1e80664d126e6fc4e5e33fcbd  129.t.extracted.crt
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you were already using `awk`, here's a solution which takes any number of bundle files. It works simply by storing the certificates as hash keys, thus automatically eliminating duplicates.

```
#!/usr/bin/gawk -f
/-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----/   { hash = "" }
                                { hash = hash $0 RS }
/-----END CERTIFICATE-----/     { hashhash[hash] = 1 }
END     { for (hash in hashhash) printf "%s", hash }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a small `awk` script (standard Linux gnu `awk`) that do the job. For any number of certificate files. It aggregate all the certificate in a set (each member is unique) and put them out.

`script.awk`

```
BEGIN {RS="-----END CERTIFICATE-----"}  # define record separator
{certArr[$0] = $0 RS;}   # capture each certificat in certArr array from input files
END {for(cert in certArr) print certArr[cert]} # print out the certificates array (not in order)
```

`certs1.pem`

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
hash1
hash1.1
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
hash2
hash2.1
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
hash3
hash3.1
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

`certs2.pem`

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
hash1
hash1.1
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
hash4
hash4.1
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
hash3
hash3.1
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

running:

```
awk -f script.awk certs*
```

output:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
hash2
hash2.1
-----END CERTIFICATE-----

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
hash4
hash4.1
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
hash1
hash1.1
-----END CERTIFICATE-----

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
hash3
hash3.1
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```